# Spring @QuerydslPredicate and QuerydslBinderCustomizer: is it possible to infuse default criteria into predicate generated from request params?

Tags: rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl, predicate

I am using **Spring Data JPA** and **QueryDsl** (v.4.2.2), Java 8. I can explicitly construct search predicates and pass them to the repository methods. However, I like the idea of using the `@QuerydslPredicate` annotation on a web/REST controller's method argument when the queried entities have more than a few properties, and I want the flexibility of filtering the search by any of them. So, something like this, generally, works very well:

```java
    @GetMapping("/accounts/summaries")
    public PageDto<AccountSummaryDto> getAccountSummaries(@QuerydslPredicate(root = AccountSummary.class) Predicate accountSearchPredicate,
            @RequestParam(name = "pageIndex", defaultValue = "0") int pageIndex,
            @RequestParam(name = "pageSize", defaultValue = "25") int pageSize,
            @RequestParam(name = "sortBy", defaultValue = "id") String sortBy,
            @RequestParam(name = "sortOrder", defaultValue = "desc") String sortOrder) {

         // delegating to web-agnostic service that:
         // - creates Pageable pageRequest,     
         // - calls accountSummaryRepository.findAll(predicate, pageRequest), 
         // - constructs custom PageDto wrapper, etc. 
         return accountService.retrieveAccountSummaries(accountSearchPredicate, pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy, sortOrder); 
    }
```

My Spring Data JPA repository interface looks similar to this:

```java
    public interface AccountSummarySearchRepository
        extends JpaRepository<AccountSummary, Integer>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<AccountSummary>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QAccountSummary > {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QAccountSummary acctSummary) {
        bindings.bind(acctSummary.customer.firstName).first((path, value) -> path.isNull().or(path.startsWithIgnoreCase(value))) ;
        bindings.bind(acctSummary.customer.lastName).first((path, value) -> path.isNull().or(path.startsWithIgnoreCase(value))) ;
        
        // etc.

        // default binding for String properties to be case insensitive "contains" match
        bindings.bind(String.class).first(
                (StringPath path, String value) -> path.isNull().or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value)));
    }
```

**My question:**

> The bindings in the `customize` method are set using the entity field
> paths and the `values` of the request parameters that match those
> paths. If the parameter is not specified, is there a way to bind the
> path to some constant value or a value obtained dynamically?

For example, I want to always *ONLY* retrieve the entities where property `deleted` is set to `false` - without forcing the client to pass that as a query parameter? Similarly, I may want to set other default lookup values dynamically for each query. For example, I may want to "retrieve only those accounts where `assignedTo` == `[current user ID available on a ThreadLocal]`...

The following will not work

```
        bindings.bind(acctSummary.deleted).first((path, value) -> path.eq(false));
```

because it, obviously, expects the *first occurrence of the path/value pair* for `deleted=...` in the Predicate (mapped from the incoming request params via the @QuerydslPredicate annotation. I don't want to pass that as a parameter because the requester does not even need to know about the existence of such field.

Is there a simple way to infuse the Predicate instance that is auto-populated via the `@QuerydslPredicate` annotation with any additional implicit/default criteria that are not explicitly passed in the web request? Could this be done in the `customize` method? I suppose, one (very ugly) way would be to intercept the HTTP request in a filter - before it is processed by the Spring-QueryDsl framework - and replace it with a new request with added parameters? That would be a horrible solution, and I feel there has to be a better way to do it via some hook/capability provided by the framework itself.

Unfortunately, there seem to be no comprehensive documentation for Spring QueryDsl support - other than some very simplistic examples.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question... I was hoping to find a hook in the framework where I could add the code to enhance the auto-generated predicate with criteria common for all my queries - before it arrives in the controller method, but wasn’t able to figure that out. Overriding `QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver` doesn't seem a good or necessary option. And, quite frankly, I've come to the conclusion that this wasn't such a great idea to begin with. It seems that any modifications to the search criteria should be done in a more obvious way - in the business tier. So I decided to simply update the predicate in the service method:

```
public PageDto<AccountSummaryDto> retrieveByPredicate(Predicate predicate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, String sortBy, String sortOrder) {
     Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.Direction.fromString(sortOrder), sortBy);

     QAccountSummary accountSummary = QAccountSummary.accountSummary; //QueryDsl auto-generated query type for AccountSummary (path root)
     
     // construct new enhanced search predicate w/added criteria common for all queries 
     // using original predicate generated by framework from request params as base
     BooleanBuilder updatedPredicate = new BooleanBuilder(predicate)
        .and(accountSummary.somethingNested.id.eq(SomeThreadContext.getSomethingId()))
        .and(accountSummary.deleted.eq(false))
        .and(accountSummary.someProperty.eq("xyz"));

     Page<accountSummary> page = summarySearchRepository.findAll(updatedPredicate, pageRequest);
     return toAccountSummaryPageDto(page); // custom method that converts results to page DTO w/entity dots and page stats
}
```

The construction of the updated predicate may be extracted into a separate private method on the service should it be desirable to use it in multiple search methods and/or if more logic is required to dynamically generate additional search criteria.